# Extract row families from linked rows

Tags: sql, plsql, self-join, listagg

I have a table of linked transactions similar to the following table

```
+----+----+----+
| #  | A  | B  |
+----+----+----+
| 1  | 1  | 4  |
| 2  | 3  | 5  |
| 3  | 4  | 6  |
| 4  | 5  | 8  |
| 5  | 6  | 1  |
| 6  | 7  | 7  |
| 7  | 8  | 3  |
| 8  | 9  | 3  |
| 9  | 10 | 4  |
| 10 | 11 | 14 |
| 11 | 2  | 2  |
| 12 | 12 | 4  |
| 13 | 13 | 14 |
| 14 | 14 | 9  |
| 15 | 15 | 1  |
+----+----+----+
```

The numbers under columns A and B represent transaction Ids. So for instance, Transaction 1 is linked with transaction 4 by some criteria, tran 3 with tran 5, tran 4 with tran 6 and so on.

Transactions 2 and 7 aren't linked to any other transaction, hence they are self-linked.

What I want to extract are transaction families from this table- Since  tran 1 and 4 are linked, tran 4 and 6 are linked, tran 10 and 4 are linked etc they come under one transacction family -(1,4,6,10,12,15).

I want to create families of transactions with the lowest transaction ID being the master transaction. 
So ideally, the output will look like this

```
+----+------+--------------+
| #  | Tran | Master_tran  |
+----+------+--------------+
| 1  | 1    | 1  |
| 2  | 3    | 3  |         
| 3  | 4    | 1  |
| 4  | 5    | 3  |
| 5  | 6    | 1  |
| 6  | 7    | 7  |
| 7  | 8    | 3  |
| 8  | 9    | 3  |
| 9  | 10   | 1  |
| 10 | 11   | 3  |
| 11 | 2    | 2  |
| 12 | 12   | 1  |
| 13 | 13   | 3  |
| 14 | 14   | 3  |
| 15 | 15   | 1  |
+----+------+----+
```

I have been toying with self-joins.

```
SELECT     t1.a as x, 
           least (min(t1.b), min(t2.a)) as y  
FROM       test   t1 
LEFT JOIN  test   t2 on t2.b = t1.a  
GROUP BY   t1.a 
ORDER BY   t1.a asc
```

This code gives the following outupt

```
+------+----+---+
| Col1 | X  | Y |
+------+----+---+
|    1 |  1 | 4 |
|    2 |  2 | 2 |
|    3 |  3 | 5 |
|    4 |  4 | 1 |
|    5 |  5 | 3 |
|    6 |  6 | 1 |
|    7 |  7 | 7 |
|    8 |  8 | 3 |
|    9 |  9 | 3 |
|   10 | 10 |   |
|   11 | 11 |   |
|   12 | 12 |   |
|   13 | 13 |   |
|   14 | 14 | 9 |
|   15 | 15 |   |
+------+----+---+
```

I am not sure what is wrong in my code. Can someone point me in the right direction? 
Thanks!

Comment: Since you never know how long the chain is going to be, you can't use just a single self-join. You need as many self-joins as there are links in the chain. This is obviously problematic because you don't know how long that is. One solution to that is to use a recursive query to continually self join until the chain ends. The problem with this is that you have circular links which will result in infinite looping. You will need to resolve that by fixing the data so it doesn't loop.

Comment: What is the max value of tran? If it's not that large, you can use a recursive query with a bitmask. Then you don't have to worry about the circular links. By small, I mean <64 or so.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

There are ~100k individual transactions, so the value of tran will exceed 64.  

How can I fix the data so it doesn't loop?

Comment: Well, maybe there's nothing to fix. At first I thought this was hierarchical data but maybe it's not. If it's not hierarchical data, then the links that create a loop aren't incorrect data per se. Rather, you just need to figure out a way to make sure you're not looping in your recursive query, perhaps by keeping a running string of traversed values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in principle you need a CONNECT BY Statement to solve such hierarchical problems.
While you have circular loops, you will also need a NOCYCLE clause, this will eliminate the last link in the loop, which is fine, as that link will never be part of the answer.
You also have links in both directions (f.e. (13, 14) and (14, 9)), so you must be careful to include that in your query (Twice!).

```
WITH t_order
     AS (SELECT qt.qt_id, qt.qt_a, qt.qt_b, LEAST( qt.qt_a, qt.qt_b ) AS t_parent, GREATEST( qt.qt_a, qt.qt_b ) AS t_child
       FROM query_test qt
     UNION
     SELECT qb.qt_id, qb.qt_a, qb.qt_b, GREATEST( qb.qt_a, qb.qt_b ) AS t_parent, LEAST( qb.qt_a, qb.qt_b ) AS t_child
       FROM query_test qb)
, hier
  AS (SELECT     ps.qt_id
              , ps.qt_a
              , ps.qt_b
              , t_parent
              , t_child
              , LEVEL
              , CONNECT_BY_ROOT t_parent AS prev_tran
           FROM t_order ps
     CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR t_child = t_parent)
SELECT   hr.qt_id, hr.qt_a, MIN( hr.prev_tran ) AS master_tran
  FROM hier hr
GROUP BY hr.qt_id, hr.qt_a
ORDER BY hr.qt_id, hr.qt_a;
```

This will solve your problem, but might get very slow if those 100.000 records must be handled.  The SQL statement also gets hard to understand if you need to combine this method with lots of other columns. For that you should factor out all qt.qt columns and join them in in the last select.

```
WITH t_order
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT tran, root_tran
           FROM (SELECT LEAST( qt.qt_a, qt.qt_b ) AS tran, GREATEST( qt.qt_a, qt.qt_b ) AS root_tran
                   FROM query_test qt
                 UNION
                 SELECT GREATEST( qb.qt_a, qb.qt_b ) AS tran, LEAST( qb.qt_a, qb.qt_b ) AS root_tran
                   FROM query_test qb))
   , hier
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT tran, root_tran
           FROM (SELECT     tran, CONNECT_BY_ROOT root_tran AS root_tran
                       FROM t_order
                 CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR tran = root_tran)
          WHERE tran >= root_tran)
SELECT   qt.qt_id
       , qt.qt_a
       , MIN( LEAST( h1.root_tran, h2.root_tran ) ) AS master_tran
    FROM query_test qt
         INNER JOIN hier h1 ON qt.qt_a = h1.tran
         INNER JOIN hier h2 ON qt.qt_b = h2.tran
GROUP BY qt.qt_id, qt.qt_a
ORDER BY qt.qt_id, qt.qt_a;
```

I could not test this last statement.

Comment: Hey ,thanks a lot for the answer, it works perfectly on the test code.
However, as you mentioned, even the second piece of code takes a lot of time to implement. I ran it for ~100 minutes before killing the process. 

Is there a way to make it quicker?

Comment: Yes, but only it is possible to rearrang those columns A and B high to low.

Comment: When A is guaranteed higher or equal to B the highest inner join (h1) and the LEAST function are not needed. That should about halve the time needed. I have an idea for a less precise solution, I'll try to post that later

Answer (score 0):

I might have created that other solution.
Instead of using a CONNECT BY statement, you could also double your links, and redouble them any time that is needed.
The query to retrieve all links stays the same but it is followed by a simple query to replace the original links with all distinct combinations of two links.
Including the link that is formed by tran_a and tran_b, you have 2 + 1 + 2 links, so you can find paths up to 5 links long.
If that is to short, you insert an identical subquery under the previous subquery, and now it is 4 + 1 + 4 makes 9 links long.
As you see, your maximum pathlength doubles for each added subquery, with only moderately more performance costs.

First the query to check your demo data:

```
WITH double_0
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT root_tran, tran
           FROM ( SELECT LEAST( td_0.tran_a, td_0.tran_b ) AS root_tran
                       , GREATEST( td_0.tran_a, td_0.tran_b ) AS tran
                    FROM tran_demo td_0
                  UNION
                  SELECT GREATEST( qb.tran_a, qb.tran_b ) AS root_tran
                       , LEAST( qb.tran_a, qb.tran_b ) AS tran
                    FROM tran_demo qb ))
   , double_1
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT oa.root_tran, ob.tran
           FROM double_0 oa INNER JOIN double_0 ob ON oa.tran = ob.root_tran)
SELECT   td_1.td_id
       , td_1.tran_a
       , MIN( LEAST( d1.root_tran, d2.root_tran ) ) AS master_tran
    FROM tran_demo td_1
         INNER JOIN double_1 d1 ON td_1.tran_a = d1.tran
         INNER JOIN double_1 d2 ON td_1.tran_b = d2.tran
GROUP BY td_1.td_id, td_1.tran_a
ORDER BY td_1.td_id, td_1.tran_a;
```

Then how you modify that:
Notice that you now query **double_2** in the final query.

```
WITH double_0
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT root_tran, tran
           FROM ( SELECT LEAST( td_0.tran_a, td_0.tran_b ) AS root_tran
                       , GREATEST( td_0.tran_a, td_0.tran_b ) AS tran
                    FROM tran_demo td_0
                  UNION
                  SELECT GREATEST( qb.tran_a, qb.tran_b ) AS root_tran
                       , LEAST( qb.tran_a, qb.tran_b ) AS tran
                    FROM tran_demo qb ))
   , double_1
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT oa.root_tran, ob.tran
           FROM double_0 oa INNER JOIN double_0 ob ON oa.tran = ob.root_tran)
   , double_2
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT oa.root_tran, ob.tran
           FROM double_1 oa INNER JOIN double_0 ob ON oa.tran = ob.root_tran)
SELECT   td_1.td_id
       , td_1.tran_a
       , MIN( LEAST( d1.root_tran, d2.root_tran ) ) AS master_tran
    FROM tran_demo td_1
         INNER JOIN double_2 d1 ON td_1.tran_a = d1.tran
         INNER JOIN double_2 d2 ON td_1.tran_b = d2.tran
GROUP BY td_1.td_id, td_1.tran_a
ORDER BY td_1.td_id, td_1.tran_a;
```

Finally a query to check if the path length you're using ist still enough:
You already add the next level and subtract your current level.
As long as this query doesn't return any rows, the current query is correct.

```
WITH double_0
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT root_tran, tran
           FROM ( SELECT LEAST( td_0.tran_a, td_0.tran_b ) AS root_tran
                       , GREATEST( td_0.tran_a, td_0.tran_b ) AS tran
                    FROM tran_demo td_0
                  UNION
                  SELECT GREATEST( qb.tran_a, qb.tran_b ) AS root_tran
                       , LEAST( qb.tran_a, qb.tran_b ) AS tran
                    FROM tran_demo qb ))
   , double_1
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT oa.root_tran, ob.tran
           FROM double_0 oa INNER JOIN double_0 ob ON oa.tran = ob.root_tran)
   , double_2
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT oa.root_tran, ob.tran
           FROM double_1 oa INNER JOIN double_0 ob ON oa.tran = ob.root_tran)
SELECT   td_1.tran_a
       , MIN( LEAST( d1.root_tran, d2.root_tran ) ) AS master_tran
    FROM tran_demo td_1
         INNER JOIN double_2 d1 ON td_1.tran_a = d1.tran
         INNER JOIN double_2 d2 ON td_1.tran_b = d2.tran
GROUP BY td_1.tran_a
MINUS
SELECT   td_2.tran_a
       , MIN( LEAST( d1.root_tran, d2.root_tran ) ) AS master_tran
    FROM tran_demo td_2
         INNER JOIN double_1 d1 ON td_2.tran_a = d1.tran
         INNER JOIN double_1 d2 ON td_2.tran_b = d2.tran
GROUP BY td_2.tran_a
ORDER BY tran_a;
```

Performance testing you will have to do yourself. 
I am optimistic while the subquery is cheap and each time the effective pathlength doubles.
Sooner or later this should become faster than the previous solution.
By the way, the remark about sorting the original links works here too!
Please mark my answer if it works.